# MySQL workbench is not working

Tags: mysql, wamp, mysql-workbench

I've only just started working with the databases. As my first step, I installed Wamp  and MySQL. Installation went smooth without any errors with help of Youtube  tutorials. The last step of MySQL installation said it would launch the workbench itself, but it didn't. When I try to open the workbench on my own, the cursor just shows loading sign and nothing happens then. Am I missing something? I'm using 32-bit Windows 7.

Comment: check this link, it will help

http://superuser.com/questions/327862/mysql-workbench-5-2-doesnt-start-on-windows-7-ultimate-64-bit

Comment: Install MySQL Workbench with the Windows Installer provided by MySQL. It checks for all required prerequisites and allows you to download and install them from within the installer, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench Prerequisites: [+]

To be able to install and run MySQL Workbench 5.2 your System needs to have libraries listed below installed. The listed items are provided as links to the corresponding download pages where you can fetch the necessary files.

```
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)
```

check this link, it will help

https://superuser.com/questions/327862/mysql-workbench-5-2-doesnt-start-on-windows-7-ultimate-64-bit